# countdown timer with class not id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How i can make this code works

```
<a href="downloadFile.zip" class="button">Download the file...</a>
```

with

```
    var downloadButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
var id;

downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

id = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0) {
        newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
    }
}, 1000);
```

I don't want to add `id="download"`

Please help me. anyone can help me? Please i need your help. Thanks

Comment: `var downloadButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];`  because `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference between `getElementById()` and `getElementsByClassName()` is that the latter returns an array, therefore you need to either loop through all elements returned or access the specific one you want by index.

As you only appear to require the first `.button` element, you can just do:

```
var downloadButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0]; // note the [0]
```

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0];
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in 10 seconds.";
var id;

downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

id = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter < 0) {
    newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
    clearInterval(id);
  } else {
    newElement.innerHTML = "You can download the file in " + counter.toString() + " seconds.";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<a href="downloadFile.zip" class="button">Download the file...</a>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help